# Unsigned char range is 0 to 255

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    unsigned char counter = 0; 
    for (counter = 0; counter <= 255; counter++) { 
        printf("%d ", counter); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Correct Output is Infinite loop 
But I thought output is 0,1,...255 because unsigned char ranges from 0 to 255 .when the counter becomes 256 then only it exceeds the range. but here our condition is counter <=255 Please clear my doubt

Comment: Can you show us the result in the console plese?

Comment: nope... counter is an unsigned char so is never ever holding the 256 value...

Comment: Changed tag to [c++] because that's what you're writing

Comment: For an `unsigned char` type with a current value of `255`, the `++` operator will make its new value `0`.

Comment: unsigned char is between 0 and 255. You check in the loop <= 255 and it will always be true. When counter is at 255 and you try to add 1 to it, it overflows and the value resets to 0.

Answer (score 5):

Think about unsigned char as a Byte:
0 -> 0b00000000
1 -> 0b00000001
...
255 -> 0b11111111

Then the next number is 0 because you can't have a 9th bit. So after 0b11111111 it's 0b00000000.

That's why it is an infinite loop, it will never reach 256 and will always stay between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 2):

This will result in infinite loop because condition `(counter <= 255)` in `if` loop is always `true`.

There is no way for this condition to be `false`: variable `counter` can not contain values higher than 255.